# Join 2 tables with multiple conditions

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Assume if I type `index=endpoints` and hit enter in the search bar, I will get results that look something like this:

```
{
  "user": Jack,
  "os_name": "Windows",
  "hostname": "Windows-JACK-01",
  "pid": "30219",
  "app": "/usr/bin/curl",
  "cmdline": "curl google.com",
  "epoch": "1503452096",
  "type": "processes"
}

. . .

{
  "hostname": "Windows-JACK-01",
  "pid": "30219",
  "app": "/usr/bin/curl",
  "epoch": "1503452096",
  "ip": "123.123.123.123",
  "port": "1234",
  "type": "sockets"
}

. . .
```

There are two types of data under the same index - sockets and processes. I would like to find a way to combine these two types of data (that are related) so that I could get a richer data that has all the information.

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+
| hostname | pid | app | osname | ip | port | etc.... |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+
| ...      | ... | ... | ...    | x  | y    | ...     |
+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

The problem is if I simply do something like:

```
index=endpoints type="processes"
| join left=L right=L WHERE L.pid=R.pid [ search index=endpoints type="sockets" ]
```

Most of the time, I will get a wrong mapping between the `app` and the `pid` because any applications can get assigned to same `pid` when it's available.

I'm thinking maybe if I add more conditions, it will reduce the inaccuracy rate. For example, instead of `L.pid=R.pid` only, maybe I could do `L.pid=R.pid AND L.hostname=R.hostname AND ...`

My naive approach was to add more condition in the WHERE part

```
index=endpoints type="processes"
| join left=L right=L WHERE (L.pid=R.pid AND L.x=R.x AND...)
  [ search index=endpoints type="sockets" ]
```

However, it seems like that's not how it works. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example queries I guess you are an experienced SQL user who is new to Splunk and hasn't read the manual about the `join` command.  `join` does not accept a `where` clause nor does it have `left` or `right` options.  As a best practice, one should avoid `join` as much as possible since it is very inefficient.

Try using `stats`, instead.  We use `stats` for its grouping feature rather than to calculate statistics.

```
index=endpoints (type="processes" OR type="sockets")
| stats values(*) as * by hostname, pid
```

Comment: That's is correct. I'm an SQL user who is migrating to Splunk :). So, I modified my query a bit to `index=endpoints (type="process" OR type="sockets") ip="123.123.0.0/16 | stats(*) bla bla bla"`. Immediately, I saw that all the `type="process"` fields disappear from the result. I believe this is because `type="process"` doesn't have an ip field, and so the stats only shows the fields from `type="sockets"` events. Is there any workarounds?

Comment: The process events are being filtered out by the base query (the part before the first pipe).  Saying "ip=123.123.0.0/16" is telling Splunk to not bother with any events that don't have an IP field or with an IP field that has a different value.  To return results with a specific IP address, use a `where` command after `stats`.  `| stats values(*) as * by hostname,pid | where ip=123.123.0.0/16`.  It's a less efficient, but should work.  The exact `where` expression may need to be tweaked depending on the content of that field and if you're trying an exact match or a CIDR match.

Comment: `join` does indeed have the ability to match on multiple fields and in either inner or outer modes. Eg: `| join fieldA fieldB type=outer` - See [join on docs.Splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/join)